# Ввод роли или пользователя в команду discord py

Tags: python, discord.py

Мне нужно сделать команду, которая бы выглядела так:

```
/voice permit <@member>/<@role>
```

Но я не знаю, как дать пользователю возможность ввести либо тег роли, либо тег пользователя одновременно.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
from typing import Union

import discord
from discord import option


bot = discord.Bot()



@bot.slash_command()
@option("permit", Union[discord.Role, discord.Member], description="Select a permit")
async def voice(ctx, permit: Union[discord.Role, discord.Member]):
    await ctx.respond(f"You selected {permit.mention} permit.")



bot.run("token")
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Достаточно, просто, объединить 2 аннотации при помощи Union (или | в python3.10+).

ВАЖНО: нужно использовать последнюю версию py-cord (то, что это возможно именно в discord.py, я сомневаюсь), если Вы использовали до этого discord.py, а не py-cord, не волнуйтесь, py-cord целиком обладает обратной совместимостью с discord.py, то есть Вам достаточно, просто, удалить discord.py и скачать py-cord, разницы не будет

Comment: спасибо, у меня теперь только вылетает ошибка Unknown interaction , скорее всего из-за того, что моя программа может ответить за время, большее чем 3 секунды, я знаю, что дискорд ждет только 3 секунды,после чего, пишет программа не отвечает.

Comment: @CookieEater 

Да верно, это происходит из-за подобной причины, попробуйте использовать асинхронный подход, чтобы выполнять задачи не постепенно, а подряд. Если нужна помощь создайте вопрос с исходниками, и я подскажу